# Algorithm to find positive and negative integer square roots (without given boundaries)

Tags: php, algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I've been practicing a lot of algorithms recently for an interview. I was wondering if there was another way to solve this problem. I wrote it in a way where I only increment it positively, because I know from basic math that two negatives multiplied by each other would result to a positive number, so I would just have to make the integer that would satisfy the condition to negative.

Is there a way to write this **elegantly** where you didn't have the knowledge of multiplying two negative numbers result to a positive?

```
<?php

# Z = {integers}
# B = {x:x, x is an element of Z,  x^2 + 1 = 10}

$numNotFound = true;
$x = 0;
$b = [];

while ($numNotFound) {
    if ($x*$x + 1 == 10) {
        array_push($b, $x, $x*-1);
        $numNotFound = false;
    }
    $x++;
}

echo json_encode($b); #[3, -3]
```

Comment: I'm confused by exactly what you are needing?

Comment: Try this `$ints = json_encode(range((PHP_INT_MAX * -1), PHP_INT_MAX));` ... or don't ... lol \s

Comment: @e_mam106  Please see updated answer.  I think it's more in line with what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated**

This solution does not use the fact that -1 * -1 = 1. It will output the first number found as the first element in the array. If x=-3 then [-3,3] or if x=3 [3,-3].

```
$numNotFound = TRUE;
$x = 0;
$b = [];

Do{

  if ((pow($x, 2) + 1) === 10) {

    array_push($b, $x, 0 - $x); 
    $numNotFound = FALSE;

  }

  $x++;

}while($numNotFound);

echo json_encode($b); //[3, -3]
```